# How do I get detailed IIS error 500 info without IE

Tags: debugging, iis, http-status-code-500

When testing on localhost, I can get detailed errors in IE like this:

```
Microsoft VBScript compilation  error '800a0409' 

Unterminated string constant 

/sitename/foldername/pagename.asp, line 204 
"
-^
```

How can I get the same in Chrome or Firefox?  IE is going away and this is really vital.

Comment: You just need to run the application in Chrome or Firefox. and why don’t you try to solve this error?

Comment: Each browser has a different kernel. If there is only a 500 error in Chrome or Firefox, it means that the browser can only do this step. if you want to get detailed error information without ie, you can try to use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was to turn on Send Errors to browser in IIS. I was thrown by the (inexplicable) fact that I got them in IE but not Chrome or FF.  No explanation for that, just observed reality.

[image]